# Best way to serialize a large amount of data using Scala 2.9

Tags: scala, serialization, bigdata

I want to serialize a Graph described as a LinkedHashMap using Scala version 2.9.3. and then deserialize/read it with another program. The amount of nodes and edges is in the range of millions and I'm planning to use Spark to parallelize the execution in the near future*. I've spent a lot of time reading about the different options but I'm still clueless about which one is the best. So, I need some advice about libraries and some links to examples.

*: That's why I use Scala 2.9.3.

Comment: Emit a compact textual representation specific to the information content of your graph's vertices and / or arcs rather than some kind of generic serialization format. Graphs are very regular structures and the bulk of what you'd be externalizing using generic serialization would be superfluous and specific to the internal representation rather than the essential content and structure of the graph.

Comment: Ok, then I just write to a file the representation?

Comment: One easy choice, possibly adequate, would be to use the format of the GraphViz tools, which would give you the added benefit of being able to visualize your graphs with that toolkit. I'm actually curious why you're not using Graph for Scala (https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-graph/wiki)? It includes I/O in a couple of different formats (export to DOT, the GraphViz format, and export and import in JSON).

Comment: Side note: Spark 1.0.0 runs on Scala 2.10, so you are not bound to version 2.9.3 in that respect.